# Accessing shell variables in Python

Tags: python, bash, shell

Running `echo $HISTFILE` in bash gives me `/home/myname/.bash_history`.

Now I'm trying to use Python to access this HISTFILE shell variable by doing the following:

```py
import subprocess
x = subprocess.check_output('echo $HISTFILE', shell=True)
print(x)
```

However, this gives me a blank output.

1. If `subprocess.check_output` along with `shell=True` executes the command in a shell, why doesn't it have a HISTFILE variable that I can access?
2. How can I work my way around this?

Comment: [`os.environ["HISTFILE"]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ).

Comment: Note that for HISTFILE to show up in the environment (os.environ), it must first be exported: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295555 I think it isn't by default.

Comment: `$HISTFILE` looks like any other environment variable but in reality it's a shell variable and you've to export it in order to access it using `os.environ` or child processes.

Answer (score 1):

Using `subprocess` seems to be overkill for the task, you can use `os.environ` to access environment variables.

```
import os
os.environ['HISTFILE']
```

Comment: That gives me a KeyError.